# Restoring messages from Nokia Ovi Suite

Tags: windows, data-recovery, nokia-ovi-suite

I had synchronized many messages from my phone to Nokia Suite, but after upgrading my computer from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Ultimate I can no longer access them. Nokia Suite gets uninstalled automatically.

I tried to launch Nokia Suite from the windows.old folder, but it says some DLL file file is missing. I copied that folder to another drive and then installed Nokia Suite again and tried to replace the folders with the old one, but still there are no previous messages.

I have deleted the windows.old folder. Can I do something? Those messages are really important.

I heard later that messages are stored in `%userprofile%\Appdata\Local\Nokia\Nokia Suite\Messages\Database`. Can I recover them with e.g. Recuva or will restoring the computer to an earlier point help?

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are stored in `%userprofile%\Appdata\Local\Nokia\Nokia Suite\Messages\Database` just navigate to your old version of the folder, copy, and paste it into the new location. When running the suite it should automatically check this folder for settings and messages and boot up just as if it was running on your old version of Windows.